# Limit approaching negative infinity question?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.. How do I get rid of the square root?

Comment: it should be fixed now!

Comment: Don't worry about the square root just yet. What's the first step you would do if there were no square root?

Comment: factor what is inside the root?

Comment: Well, that's still thinking about the root :) Think about this: what is the highest power of polynomial that appears in the equation?

Comment: take common factor of the terms with larger exponent in both denominator an numerator, and take the 9x^6 outside the square root. The rest will limit to one.

Comment: highest power is 6...

Comment: so outside the square root you will have 3x^3 (what is left inside the square root converges to 1. Same with the denominator.

Comment: @julianfernandez importantly, you'll actually have $3\left| x \right| ^3$

Comment: that is right! missed it

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: @user148748: So maybe I come later. The answer may be not useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{5x^2-2x^3+9x^6}}{-17+3x+8x^3}
=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{-x^3\sqrt{5\frac{1}{x^4}-2\frac{1}{x^3}+9}}{-17+3x+8x^3}
=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{5\frac{1}{x^4}-2\frac{1}{x^3}+9}}{\frac{17}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^2}-8}=-\frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: I got the answer already but this was also very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @user148748: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Setting $h=-\dfrac1x,$

$$F=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{5x^2-2x^3+9x^6}}{-17+3x+8x^3}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{5h^4-2h^3+9}/\sqrt{h^6}}{(-17h^3+3h^2+8)/h^3}$$

As $h>0,h\ne0$ and $\sqrt{h^6}=+h^3$

$$F=\frac{\sqrt{5\cdot0^4-2\cdot0^3+9}}{-17\cdot0^3+3\cdot0^2+8}=?$$